# How to align ul elements properly?

Tags: html, css

I have list elements which is not formatted properly. How to arrange it in table format so that it looks clean and neat.Following is the code for reference

Details.js

```
<ul className="extras"> 
                {extras.map((item, index) => {
                    return <li key={index}>
                    <img src={starImage} height="10%" width="10%" /> {item}</li>
                })}
</ul>
```

App.css

```
.extras {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 10rem;
  grid-row-gap: 1rem;
}
```

Below is the end result 
[image]

The arrangement of list doesn't look good. Any good solution so that it's aligned properly.

Comment: Css-grid is not exactly a suitable replacement for css-tables unless using fixed column widtgs6

Comment: Try `justify-items: start;` to your `grid`

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh No changes

Comment: I would suggest you to use flexbox. 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

You'll get to learn something new and also be able to manipulate your HTML elements easily.

Answer (score 0):

you can use table tags for this..

```
  <tr className=""> 
            {extras.map((item, index) => {
                return 
           <td key={index}>
                <img src={starImage} height="10%" width="10%" /> {item}</td>
            })}
 </tr>
```

Comment: No changes happened... Any CSS changes?

Comment: display:grid;         justify-items: start;